# React Native how to get the local time format of device?

Tags: react-native

I need to get the time format from local device . And I have tried this "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-time-format?activeTab=readme"

And also install the moment API and follow what the document said ,however ,when I tried ,it got an error like "
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNDeviceTimeFormat.is24HourFormat')

"
I attached my code ,could you please help me to take a look ? Thank you so much !!

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { is24HourFormat } from 'react-native-device-time-format';
import moment from 'moment'

function TryTime(props) {
    const getCurrentHourFormat = async (date) => {
        const is24Hour = await is24HourFormat();
        return (moment(date).format(is24Hour ? 'HH:mm' : 'h:mm A'));
      }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{is24Hour}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
    }
})
export default TryTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code: you defined a function `getCurrentHourFormat` but haven't run it yet, so `is24Hour` is undefined.

```
function TryTime(props) {
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState("");

    const getCurrentHourFormat = async (date) => {
        const is24Hour = await is24HourFormat();
        return (moment(date).format(is24Hour ? 'HH:mm' : 'h:mm A'));
      }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const timeNow = await TryTime(Date.now);
            setCurrentTime(timeNow);
        })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{currentTime}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

You might want to check `useEffect` and how functional component work though

Comment: Hi Quan ,sorry that I had tried again ,but it seems not work again ..I am sure if I did wrong ,I had corried your code and run it ,but not work .. Could you please check it out ? Thank you so much for your kindness!